# DisplayNameFor for interface deriving from IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

`HtmlHelper<T>.DisplayNameFor()` works flawlessly when I declare a `IEnumerable<T>` as the view model, giving me intellisense support for the actual typed model etc.

```
@model IEnumerable<MyModel>

// e.g. for <th>
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
```

However when I declare a custom type deriving from `IEnumerable<T>`, it suddenly stops working.

```
@model IPagedList<MyModel>

@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id) // Cannot resolve symbol 'Id'
```

whereas `IPagedList<T>` is:

```
public interface IPagedList<T> : IEnumerable<T> {}
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just how overload resolution works in C#. Given

```
public static void DoSomething<T>(T t)
{ }

public static void DoSomething<T>(IEnumerable<T> t)
{ }
```

then `DoSomething(new int[0])` will call the `T` overload with `T = int[]` rather than the `IEnumerable<T>` overload with `T = int`.

This is because the "conversion" from `int[]` to `T` is "better" in the former case (where `T = int[]` than the conversion from `int[]` to `IEnumerable<T>` in the latter case (where `T = int`). (See `7.5.3.2 Better function member` and `7.5.3.3 7.5.3.3 Better conversion from expression` in the C# specification.)

I think your only option now is to use `.First()` in order to specify that you are accessing an element of the model:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Id)
```

Comment: Worth noting that calling `First()` assumes that it isn't empty.

Comment: @dav_i I don't think so - I think the helper doesn't *call* the lambda passed to it, just uses it as an expression tree. I'm pretty sure `[0]` works on an `IList` even if it's empty, but I don't know if the helper is clever enough to use `First` as well.

Comment: @Rawling *You can cast your IPagedList<T> back to IEnumerable<T>* Where'd I need to cast it and how? I tried casting it inside the property selector expression, 'model => ((IEnumerable<MyModel>model).Id', however it's still unable to resolve the property.

Comment: @xvdiff Good point, I didn't think that through. You might have to use `.First()`.